# checkout_cart_add_product_complete not working for programmatically added product

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, catalog

In my magento store, I have a script to add product programmatically in cart using below code :

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$params = array(    
        'product' => $_product->getId(),
        'qty' => $qty,
        'options' =>'',
        'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()              
    );

$cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
$cart->save();
```

For this item `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event not fired.

However the `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event is working nice while adding a product to cart from a catalog.

Is there any other event in magento which fire on programmatically add product (similar to `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dispatch your custom event after you code.

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$params = array(    
    'product' => $_product->getId(),
    'qty' => $qty,
    'options' =>'',
    'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()              
);

$cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
$cart->save();
/***My Custom Event***/    
    Mage::dispatchEvent('custom_cart_add_product_event',array('product' => $_product));
/***My Custom Event***/
```

Now just like magento event you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you check `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php::addAction`, you will see that the event is fired using below code,

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
);
```

So, to call the event, you have to use the same code in your function after you save cart.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this :

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$params = array(    
        'product' => $_product->getId(),
        'qty' => $qty,
        'options' =>'',
        'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()              
    );

$cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
$cart->save();
```

There was a issue in your 3rd line:

Comment: That was a typing mistake, product added in cart successfully with my script, my question is `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event not fired.